# Convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3 - n}}$ using the comparison test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I find the convergence of this summation using the comparison test?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3 - n}}
\end{equation}

I am not sure what the comparison sequence would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Compare with
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.
$$